# Seleccion de checkbox con valor igual a los valores del POST

Tags: php, javascript

Ocupo que al abrir la lista de los chekbox, se seleccionen automaticamente los checkbox con el mismo id que traigo desde un array

```
<?php          $id=0;
                    while ($clientes = pg_fetch_object($Cat))
                    {

                        if ($numfila == 0){ $class = "alt"; $numfila = 1; } else { $class = ""; $numfila = 0; }
                            echo "<tr class'".$class."' style=\"height: 5px;\">";

                                echo "<td align='center'>".$clientes->num_suc."</td>";
                                echo "<td align='left'>".$clientes->nom_suc."</td>";

                                //if ($clientes->sucursal = 0)
                             //  $asignada = array("$asignadas");
                                if (in_array($clientes->sucursal,$asignadas)){
                                    echo "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='cod[]' checked value='".$clientes->folio."'/>";
                                else
                                    echo "<td align='center'> <input type='checkbox' name='cod[]'  value='".$clientes->folio."'/>";


                            echo "</tr>";
                            $id=$id+1;
                    }
                    if( $id == 0 )
                        echo "Sin Sucursales Para Asignar"


      ?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no mejoras tu pregunta, sin tener que obligarnos a leer el código y a tratar de adivinar la lógica del mismo. Además, el código no es legible del todo, ya que hay elementos de tu PHP que no podemos saber lo que son ni lo que contienen? Explica: 1. ¿Qué es **_la lista de los checkbox_**? 2. ¿Qué es **_el mismo id que traigo desde un array_**? 3. ¿Cómo está constituido ese **_array_** del que hablas? Si formulas la pregunta explicando esos puntos tendrás sin duda una o varias respuestas que te serán de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías tener una tabla llamada sucursal, luego hacer un **select * From sucursal** 
con ello tu obtendrías todos los nombres de tu sucursales.

```
   while($sucursales = pg_fetch_object($sur)){ 
         if ($sucursales->folio==$clientes->folio){ // clientes esta declarada arriba en tu codigo.
           echo "<td align='center'>'".$clientes->nombre."'<input type='checkbox' name='cod[]' checked value='".$clientes->folio."'/>";
          }else{
            echo "<td align='center'>'".$sucursales->nombre."'<input type='checkbox' name='cod[]'  value='".$sucursales->folio."'/>"; 
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            $id=$id+1;
    }
```

no veo el nombre del sucursal pues lo correcto es que tuvieras una tabla clientes otra para sucursal por ende obtendrías por inner join el id de sucursal tanto como el nombre del mismo , tu problema es con este if, al compilar tu código solo se debería mostrar los campos seleccionados , lo que yo entendí es que quieres establecer una diferencia y ver los seleccionados como los que no